# Scroll to Bottom of TableView before ViewController Loads

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm trying to get my TableView to scroll to the bottom before the user sees the TableView. Right now, I have it set up so that when the page loads, the user sees the TableView and then instantly sees it scroll to the bottom. I need it to be at the bottom beforehand, so the user doesn't have to see it scroll. Anyone know how to do this?

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIToolbarDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    func scrollToBottom() {
        let numberOfSections = self.chatTableView.numberOfSections
        let numberOfRows = self.chatTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfSections-1)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: numberOfRows-1 , section: numberOfSections-1)

        self.chatTableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        scrollToBottom()
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:
Just to let you know what I've tried, I ran the method in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad but that gave me an error. I think it has to do with the numberOfRows being dynamic and table having not loaded yet. I tried setting animation to false but that just makes the user see the page jump down fast, they're still seeing movement. I tried putting the method in the celForRow at so it might run after getting the messages but that didn't work. I have a method to retrieve the messages from a database and I tried putting my scrollToBottom method at the end of that but it didn't work either. I don't think it's just an issue of placement, I think there's something else I need to add but no one has been any help yet.

Comment: *...before ViewController Loads* is impossible. Put it in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: That gives me this error:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffffc)

Comment: Set the `animated` property in `scrollToRow` to `false`

Comment: You have to call `scrollToBottom()` **after** the data source was  populated.

Comment: @Malik That still shows it jump from the top to the bottom, it just does it without animation.

Comment: Did you put `scrollToBottom` in `viewWillAppear`? Make sure that the data is already populated by that time as @vadian suggested

Comment: Yeah I figured it had to be populated first but no matter where I put it, it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Do as this,

Call your method in `viewWillAppear`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
 super.viewWillAppear(true)
    scrollToBottom()
}
```

// make your animation as `false` in `scrollToRow`

```
func scrollToBottom() {

    let numberOfSections = self.chatTableView.numberOfSections
    let numberOfRows = self.chatTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfSections-1)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: numberOfRows-1 , section: numberOfSections-1)

    self.chatTableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: false)

}
```

Comment: That gives me an error. I think the problem is that the number of rows is dynamic. It depends on what was entered into the database. So when it tries to scroll to the bottom in viewWillAppear, it doesn't know where the bottom is.